# Green artifact in WebM video

Tags: javascript, video, ffmpeg, webm, web-mediarecorder

I'm recording a canvas with the MediaRecorder web api. The resulting WebM video looks good in most players (has artifacts in some), but if I convert it to mp4 with `ffmpeg -i out.webm out.mp4`, some strange green artifacts appear on the bottom of it (in every player). Anyone knows why this happens?

The WebM video: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1RQb_610nIN_s974ZRoquApr5ZUWzYJKk/view?usp=drivesdk

The corrupted MP4 output:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1RVWSOBwpo0FKTGKPmkbBcHdkXtbHbLVc/view?usp=drivesdk

Thank you in advance

Comment: For what it's worth, both kinds of video are encoded in YUV .. that is, with one number Y for the brightness of each pixel and two (U, V) for the color. Green means the U and V values are zero.

Comment: @O.Jones So do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I still don't know what this artifact is, but I found what's causing it. It happens if you create two MediaRecorders at the same time. I separated their creation at different times and now it works fine.

Comment: You may want to open an issue for your browser's vendor to fix this bug. For Chrome/Chromium it's https://crbug.com for Firefox https://bugzilla/mozilla.org, for Safari/WebKit it's https://bugs.webkit.org/